# Serve HTML from CDN. Add personalization through AJAX or cookies?

Tags: ajax, caching, cookies, cloudflare

I'm working on a website that is mostly static.  Most pages contain minor personalized components (i.e. omnipresent login / account header element, UI banners based on user attributes, etc).

I'd like to set up page rules in CloudFront to cache and serve the static HTML.  Personalization would occur via javascript DOM changes.

Would a standard approach here be to grab the dynamic data from the server via an AJAX call (which would return specific state as JSON)?

Alternatively, the server could use readable cookies to set state.

The former seems more extensible. The downside is that it comes at the cost of an extra AJAX request per page.

The latter will not work in the case where the first page encountered on the website is served from the CloudFlare cache.  The strategy will also potentially grow unwieldy with too many cookies.

Are there any other clear pros or cons to these approaches?